# Is there a way to separate each node in SelectNodes?

Tags: c#, html-table, descendant, selectnodes

The problem I am facing is to use SelectNode and scrape a table from the internet and put it into a DataGridView. My code works almost the way I want it but I get all "th" together instead of seperatly. An exmaple would be:

```
<th>1hello world<th>
<th>!<th>
<th>How was your day<th>
```

The result I then get is (which is in one long string):

`Hello world ! How was your day`

instead it should be (under the descendant  should be separated in a new column and when finished go to a new row):

```
Hello world
!
How was your day
```

The code SelectNode that works and where I have tried to change and manipulate:

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id=\"cr_cashflow\"]/div[2]/div/table")
                                            .Descendants("tr")
                                            .Select(th => th.InnerText.Trim())
                                            .ToList();

foreach (var tables in table)
{
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { tables.ToString() });
}
dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;
```

From my understanding .Select is that part where the code adds all "th" together. I have therefore tried to add additional Select, Descendants etc. but without success. Is there some code I can add to either separate each  (in the table it´s the seperate cells) or add a split so each  is in a different column and that the next  starts from a new row?

Edit:
First 2 rows is what I want to get out and the last 2 rows is what I get

[More detailed picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPMy1.png)

Comment: It looks correct, how are you printing the information out? Try using a for loop against table and use a Console.WriteLine to see if they are still joined together

Comment: I call out a datatable and import the information through a foreach loop. It´s then shown with dataGridView.datasource=dataTable link. Everything is linked through out the entire code. When I call out "var table" the information is all in one string. Thats why i´m focusing on the SelectNode but I dont have any more ideas how to make each <th> a separete cell in my table

Comment: How are you calling it out of the datatable, because your select statement isn't the issue. You select statement will just return a IEnumerable<string> and then your tolist will change it to List<string>, so its after this which is causing the issue

Comment: I have added some more code that would answer your question. Doesnt seem like anything else than .tolist() will work properly. Do you think i´m missing something in between the foreach loop and documentnode?

Comment: The original document has errors.  You need to fix the errors to get correct results.  You can add code in the foreach loop to correct some of these errors, but in probably better to fix the issues that created the bad rows in the document.